# Programming test on algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, array-algorithms

I was given this question in a programming test for an IT company.
I will try my best to explain it.

The problem is as follows:

Given an Ant at origin (0,0) which moves only in clockwise direction( takes only right turns) on a given path array. so for example if the path array is {2,3,4,5,7} the ant moves 2 units left, then moves 3 units down , then moves 4 units right, then moves 5 units up and then 7 units left so on and so forth.

So write a code which displays the ant's final position(coordinates) and state if the ant intersects it's path in the format:

Ant: (x1,y1) :(yes / no)

for example:
(1) array={1,6,3,5,4}
output: Ant: (2,-1) :yes

showing it graphically

```
         (0, 0)__(1,0)
                    |
 (-2,-1)   __ __ __ __(2,-1)
        |           |
        |           |
        |           |
        |           |
        |           |
  (-2,-6)  __ __ __    (1,-6)
```

here the ant is intersecting its path at (1,-1)

(2) array={2,2,2,1}
output: Ant: (0,-1) :no

showing it graphically

```
(0, 0)__ __(2,0)
 .(0,-1)    |
 |          |
(0,-2)__ __(2,-2)
```

here the ant doesn't intersect its path.

I wrote a code to find the final position:

```
public class Ant {

    static void findAnt(int arr[])
    {
        int count = 0;
        int x=0,y=0;
        for(int element: arr){
            if(count>3)
                count = 0;

            switch(count++){

            case 0: x=x+element;
                    break;
            case 1: y=y-element;
                    break;
            case 2: x=x-element;
                    break;
            case 3: y=y+element;
                    break;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Ant: "+x+" "+y);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = new int[]{2,2,2,1};
        findAnt(arr);
    }


}
```

However I cannot devise an algorithm that shows if the ant intersects or not.
Please advise.

Comment: Create a boolean array, fill it all to false, then when an ant would "walk" on that tile, flip it to true. Then when you have the ants final position check if that tile is already true, if so then it's been there before.

Comment: Thanks @user123, If you could  elaborate your solution, it would be of great help?

Comment: Create a `boolean[][] gameBoard`, you can make it `n * n` in size, initialize it to false. Then start looping through your array of movements, as the ant walks along each index flip the value to `true` (it's been there). Then when you get to the last index in your movements array, you check to see if the tile is already `true`, if it is, then you've been there already.

Comment: @user123: what if the path of the ant intersects with itself on a tile which is not the last one the ant visits?  :)

Comment: Another way of doing this is to create a whole bunch of lines (ants starting point to end point), then doing a point in line test, where the point is the ants ending position against all of the lines.

Comment: @dingalapadum if I am understanding you correctly, it doesn't matter if the ant walks over the same `{x,y}` position multiple times, you only care if it's been there once before.

Comment: @user123 yes, and what I am saying is that OP asked whether "the ant intersects it's path". Not if the final field where the ant arrives is intersecting. Look at OPs example: {1,6,3,5,4}. The answer is "Yes" but it's the first time the ant arrives at (2,-1), i.e. the intersection of the path happens at some other place (1, -1)

Comment: Ah I see, I misread that. In that case you just need to modify my idea slightly. Just do an `if` check on every tile it lands on, if it's already been there then if it already has been there add the coords into a List.

Comment: @user123 well, that would work. Then again it's a bit a naive approach. Think about it: your algorithm gets worse as the numbers get larger (note: not for more numbers, but larger numbers). What I mean is the following: in general you don't want an algorithm runtime to depend on the input values but rather on the size of the input. Consider the number of operations your algo does for {1, 1, 1, 5} vs the number of ops it does for {10, 10, 10, 15} - well the number of operations for those two inputs should probably be the same.

Comment: @dingalapadum Obviously this isn't the best approach, however it the context of being asked this in an interview it's a quick way to get a working solution.

Comment: @user123 fair enough, then my follow up question for you  would be: what's the running time? Can you do any better? ;)

Comment: Run-time: `O(n^2)`, Space: `O(m^2)`; With this solution I can't think of a way to reduce run-time, you could reduce space complexity by only keeping track of lines (start point, and end point), then doing line-line intersects between them to know if the ant ever crosses over. But you would still be running in `O(n^2)`, your space would go down to `O(m)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128749/discussion-between-dingalapadum-and-user123).

Answer (score 1):

It will horizontally intersect if `arr[1] <= arr[3]` and vertically if `arr[0] <= arr[2]` you just need to check these positions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if (i == arr.length-2)
         return false;//prevents indexoutofbounds
     if (arr[i] <= arr[i+2])
         return true;//intersects
}
```

this should check to see if p0 is less than p2, p1, is less than p3, and p2 is less than p4, and so on.

```
boolean intersect = false;



    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i] == arr[arr.length-2]){//i changed this
                intersect = false;//prevents indexoutofbounds
                break;

            }
            if (arr[i] <= arr[i+2])
                intersect =  true;//intersects
                break;
       }
```

and then print out intersect

Comment: in your code you will need to break out of the loop when you find either true or false, since you cant use a return

Comment: I am afraid it isn't working. for array={2,2,2,1} it outputs true even though the ant doesn't intersect.

Comment: I got false, i'll show you how i implemented it,

Comment: oh, i know why, change the <= to  <. I was assuming if they touched it counted as an intersect.

Comment: Although it worked for some test cases , it didn't  work on all, I considered an array={5,6,3,5,4} and when executed it the output came out to be  false.

Comment: I've been trying to figure that out, after I posted it I realized that may happen. The indexoutofbounds issue is what would have to be dealt with to fix that.

Comment: How did you come up with: _It will horizontally intersect if `arr[1] <= arr[3]` and vertically if `arr[0] <= arr[2]` you just need to check these positions._ Can you please explain this further: consider the following path: `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}`. If I understood the task correctly, this should output false. However: for all `i` it holds that `arr[i] <= arr[i+2]`... am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, you found a case that needs to be handled. Didnt think about it if one vertical side is shorter than another.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that doesn't keep a grid in memory, is to keep a set of visited locations in memory. This has the advantage that you don't need to know the boundary of the ant's potential path in advance. Whether it takes more or less memory than a grid, depends on the size of the grid, and the length of the ant's journey.

```
public class VisitedTileLog {

      Set visitedTiles = new HashSet<Coordinates>();
      boolean hasIntersected = false;

      public void logVisit(Coordinates c) {
          if(! visitedTiles.add(c)) {
              hasIntersected = true;
          }
      }

      public boolean hasIntersected() {
          return hasIntersected;
      }
}
```

Of course you need a `Coordinates` class with `equals()` and `hashCode()`:

```
public class Coordinates {
     private int x,y;

     public Coordinates(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
     }

     public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Let your IDE write this, or read up on best practice.
     }

     public int hashCode() {
        // Let your IDE write this, or read up on best practice.
     }

     // Examples of other methods this might have...
     public int getX() { ... }
     public int getY() { ... }
     public Coordinates move(int distance, Direction direction);
}
```

Now you can take your ant for a walk, and each time it moves, update `hasIntersected`:

```
 VisitedTileLog log = new VisitedTileLog();
 for(int distance : distances) {
      ...
      log.logVisit(...);
      ...
 }
```

This class could be enhanced with convenience methods that log a whole step's line -- `logVisit(Coordinates from, Coordinates to)` or `logVisit(Coordinates start, int distance, CompassPoint direction)`.

Depending on the interviewer, a solution like this might get you extra credit for being object-oriented. Indeed, this class could be enhanced to solve the whole of the problem, if it also maintained a `currentPosition` field.

Comment: You are still brute forcing. Since the ant only makes the same turns, the steps it made quickly become irrelevant (a path intersecting old segments must necessarily intersect a newer one). In the worst case, only 5 last segments must be traced.

Comment: @user58697 that last sentence is the crucial observation that needs to be done. Only the last 5 segments must be traced. Congrats you solved the puzzle. With this knowledge the linear time solution should be really easy to implement...

Comment: This is a fair point, and the approach I've described could be enhanced to age-off logged squares after their usefulness has passed. It could also store a list of lines rather than squares, and calculate intersections in a more sophisticated way. With unlimited time I would start with this brute-force solution, write unit tests, then refine it to be smarter.

Comment: @slim hey! can you describe the coordinate class's methods for a better understanding? thanks.

Comment: @dingalapadum . consider this test case path={2,2,3,3,4,2,2} ,if we see the last 5 segments  the ant doesn't intersect anywhere. although it intersects with the 1st segment.

Comment: @VedantAggrawal I'm not quite sure about what you are saying.. I might be missing something... Running through your example, I'd say you do intersect with segment number 2... and even if the last segment was aligned with the first one you'd still touch segment number 2, wouldn't you?

Comment: @VedantAggrawal `Coordinates` would contain (as a minimum) two integer fields, `x` and `y`. `hashcode()` and `equals()` (a good IDE will write these for you). Depending on how rigorous you want to be, you could make the fields public, or have getters and setters, or initialise the fields in the constructor and only have getters (making it immutable).

Comment: I am so sorry . It will interest with the second segment. But still the problem stays the same i guess ?

Comment: @dingalapadum I think you're saying that to evaluate whether line *n* intersects with the path, you only have to check lines starting at line *n*-4. But you still have to check each line as you make it.

Comment: @slim I'm saying you should keep a queue<segments> of fixed size (5). When creating a new segment check against elements 0, 1, 2, 3 (you'll always intersect element number 4). Then remove the first element and put the newly created segment at the end of the queue. This will make that for each point in the path you do a constant number of operations (create segment + 4 checks) rather than O(n) checks (checking against _all_ the other segments)

Comment: @VedantAggrawal I don't know.. As I said, I might be missing something, but _I_ can't see the problem

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to draw the line during each move for reference. And check before every move that if it is encountering the same coordinate that is already drawn. Below is the code for this approach. You can definitely fine tune it , but here is one way to tackle it.

**Steps :**
    Create `Coordinate` type to store coordinates.
   Create `Ant` that can hold :
  `current coordinate`: this will hold the Ant Current Coordinate at any time
  `Direction to Move next` : right , left , up or down
  data set to keep track of `traversed coordinate`
  data structure to hold all `coordinates that are revisited`

Now on every move of `ant`, it knows what direction to move next. And in each move , we draw all coordinates in between the current coordinate and the end point , and store them in traversed coordinate `set`. If there is hit, we store it in intersected coordinate `set` instead.

At the end, `current coordinate` of `ant` gives us the final `coordinate` and the line crosses over if the intersected `set` is `not empty.`

Here is the long code , that I assume is working fine.

```
public class PathCross {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] movementArray = { 2, 2, 2, 1 };// {1,6,3,5,4};
    PathCross driver = new PathCross();
    Ant ant = driver.new Ant();

    for (int i : movementArray) {
        ant.move(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Ant: (" + ant.currentCoordinate.getX() + "," + ant.getCurrentCoordinate().getY() + ") :"
            + !ant.getIntersectingCoordinates().isEmpty());
}

class Ant {

    Coordinate currentCoordinate = new Coordinate(0, 0);
    Direction nextDirection = Direction.RIGHT;

    Set<Coordinate> intersectingCoordinates = new HashSet<>();

    Set<Coordinate> traversedCoordinateSet = new HashSet<>();

    public Ant() {
        traversedCoordinateSet.add(new Coordinate(0, 0));
    }

    public Coordinate getCurrentCoordinate() {
        return currentCoordinate;
    }

    public void setCurrentCoordinate(Coordinate currentCoordinate) {
        this.currentCoordinate = currentCoordinate;
    }

    public Direction getNextDirection() {
        return nextDirection;
    }

    public void setNextDirection(Direction nextDirection) {
        this.nextDirection = nextDirection;
    }



    public Set<Coordinate> getIntersectingCoordinates() {
        return intersectingCoordinates;
    }

    public void setIntersectingCoordinates(Set<Coordinate> intersectingCoordinates) {
        this.intersectingCoordinates = intersectingCoordinates;
    }

    public Set<Coordinate> getTraversedCoordinateSet() {
        return traversedCoordinateSet;
    }

    public void setTraversedCoordinateSet(Set<Coordinate> traversedCoordinateSet) {
        this.traversedCoordinateSet = traversedCoordinateSet;
    }

    public void move(int distance) {
        Coordinate newCoordinate = null;
        switch (nextDirection) {

        case RIGHT:
            newCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX() + distance, currentCoordinate.getY());
            for (int i = currentCoordinate.getX() + 1; i <= (currentCoordinate.getX() + distance); i++) {
                if (!traversedCoordinateSet.add(new Coordinate(i, currentCoordinate.getY()))) {
                    intersectingCoordinates.add(new Coordinate(i, currentCoordinate.getY()));
                }

            }
            nextDirection = Direction.DOWN;
            break;

        case DOWN:
            newCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX(), currentCoordinate.getY() - distance);
            for (int i = currentCoordinate.getY() - 1; i >= (currentCoordinate.getY() - distance); i--) {
                if (!traversedCoordinateSet.add(new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX(), i))) {
                    intersectingCoordinates.add(new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX(), i));
                }
            }
            nextDirection = Direction.LEFT;
            break;

        case LEFT:
            newCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX() - distance, currentCoordinate.getY());
            for (int i = currentCoordinate.getX() - 1; i >= (currentCoordinate.getX() - distance); i--) {
                if (!traversedCoordinateSet.add(new Coordinate(i, currentCoordinate.getY()))) {
                    intersectingCoordinates.add(new Coordinate(i, currentCoordinate.getY()));
                }
            }
            nextDirection = Direction.UP;
            break;

        case UP:
            newCoordinate = new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX(), currentCoordinate.getY() + distance);
            for (int i = currentCoordinate.getY() + 1; i <= (currentCoordinate.getY() + distance); i++) {
                if (!traversedCoordinateSet.add(new Coordinate(currentCoordinate.getX(), i))) {
                    intersectingCoordinates.add(new Coordinate(i, currentCoordinate.getY()));
                }
            }
            nextDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
            break;

        default:
            System.err.println("ERRor");

        }

        this.currentCoordinate = newCoordinate;

    }

}

enum Direction {
    LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT, UP;
}

class Coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Coordinate() {

    }

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Coordinate other = (Coordinate) obj;
        if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
            return false;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private PathCross getOuterType() {
        return PathCross.this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The problem is hard to find out whether it intersect the previous paths. I create a boolean to record whether it is increase the circle or not. if it is always increasing, it will not intersect the previous paths. If it change to the decreasing, once it began to increasing again, it will intersects the paths. Otherwise, it will not intersects the path

```
def ant(arr):
    length = len(arr)
    x = sum(arr[::4]) - sum(arr[2:][::4])
    y = sum(arr[3:][::4]) - sum(arr[1:][::4]) 
    if length < 4:
        return x, y, False
    t1, (t2, t3, t4) = 0, arr[:3]
    increase = (t2 < t4)
    for i in xrange(3, length):
        t5 = arr[i]
        if increase and t3 >= t5:
            if t1 + t5 - t3 < 0 or i+1 < length and arr[i+1] + t2 - t4 < 0:
                increase = False
            elif i + 1 < length:
                return x, y, True

        elif not increase and t3 <= t5:
            return x, y, True
        t1, t2, t3, t4 = t2, t3, t4, t5
    return x, y, False
```